# Can I Replace SimpleRow with Image if no modelData avaliable

Tags: qt, listview, model, qml, v-play

I have a `ListView`, where the currently displayed `modelData` changes as a button cycles through several *department* options. If one of these departments has no data, my `delegate` continues showing the previous list data until it reaches a new section of `modelData` with data.

What I want to do, is when the model is 'empty' (being undefined, which may happen when the key it's looking for is yet to be created in my Firebase Database, or no items are currently visible), text/image is shown instead; i.e, "Move along now, nothing to see here".

My model is drawn from JSON, an example is below. and my `calendarUserItems` is the root node of multiple children within my Firebase Database, the aim of my `AppButton.groupCycle` was too add a further direction to each child node, filtering the data by this to view and edit within the page.

A sample of my code is:

```
Page {
id: adminPage

property var departments: [1,2,3,4]
property int currGroupIndex: 0

    AppButton {
        id: groupCycle   
        text: "Viewing: " + departments[currGroupIndex]
        onClicked: {
            if (currGroupIndex == departments.length - 1)
                currGroupIndex = 0;
            else
                currGroupIndex++;
        }
    }

    ListView {

        model: Object.keys(dataModel.calendarUserItems[departments[currGroupIndex]])

        delegate: modelData.visible ? currentGroupList : emptyHol

        Component {
            id: emptyHol
            AppText {
                text: "nothing to see here move along now!"
            }
        }
        Component {
            id: currentGroupList
            SimpleRow {
                id: container                

                readonly property var calendarUserItem: dataModel.calendarUserItems[departments[currGroupIndex]][modelData] || {}

                visible: container.calendarUserItem.status === "pending" ? true : false
                 // only pending items visible
                 // remaining code for simple row
            }
        }
    }
}
```

an example of JSON within my `dataModel.calendarUserItems` is:

```
"groupName": [
    { "department1": 
        { "1555111624727" : {
              "creationDate" : 1555111624727,
              "date" : "2019-03-15T12:00:00.000",
              "name" : "Edward Lawrence",
              "status": "pending"
             },
//several of these entries within department1
        },
    },
    { "department2":
        { "1555111624727" : {
              "creationDate" : 1555111624456,
              "date" : "2019-05-1T12:00:00.000",
              "name" : "Katie P",
              "status": 1
             },
//several of these entries within department2
        },
    }
//departments 3 & 4 as the same
]
```

If departments 2 and 3 have `modelData`, yet 1 and 4 do not, I want the text to display instead, and the `ListView` emptied, instead of showing the previous `modelData`.

I have tried playing with the image/text visibility but the issue lays more with clearing the `modelData` and I'm unsure where to begin?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what about `delegate: someCondition ? Component1 : Component2`?

Comment: Hi @folibis thanks for the direction, I have tried things such as `delegate: if(Object.keys(dataModel.calendarUserItems[departments[currGroupIndex]]).length > 0` or `!= {}` but am only receving errors on the bool `?` unexpected token '?' to check if the model data is not empty, or if it has objects within using length?

Comment: @folibis I've been playing around with your suggestion since my previous comment, and are still unable to make any headway - where my `modelData`, is from an array, and certain items are not `visible`, I cannot do things such as `model.count > 0 ? Component1 : Component2`, what could my options be to either check if either there is no `modelData` at all, or if there is no `visible` items in the `SimpleRow` delegate?

Comment: `modelData` couldn't be empty since the engine takes model as an array and apply reference to each item as `modelData` to a delegate item. As for the `visible` property, could you use `delegate: modelData.visible ? Component1 : Component2`?

Comment: Hi @folibis I think the main problem I have at current is with my `readonly property var calendarUserItem: dataModel.calendarUserItems[departments[currGroupIndex]][modelData] || {}` as when the `currGroupIndex` has no data, visible or in the database, it errors and does not remove the previous `currGroupIndex` view?

Comment: The problem is the logic, application architecture. You have to provide clear and simple API. I really can't understand what this array of arrays of arrays should do ...

Comment: Hi @folibis the data is pulled from firebase - so in JSON, when pressing the button and changing the `currGroupIndex` you are actually altering the viewable path, so department1, department2, department3 ect should direct you to that child node of the full data.I will update my question soon with further details also

Comment: @folibis I've updated my question with further information! Hopefully its clearer now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have achieved the display by using the following as my delegate:

```
delegate: {
  if (!(departments[currGroupIndex] in dataModel.calendarUserItems) ) {
    return emptyHol;
  }
  var subgroups = Object.keys(dataModel.calendarUserItems[departments[currGroupIndex]]);
  for (var i in subgroups) {
    var subgroup = dataModel.calendarUserItems[departments[currGroupIndex]][subgroups[i]];
    modelArr.push(subgroup);
  }
  var modelObect = modelArr.find( function(obj) { return obj.status === "pending"; } );
  
  if (modelObect === undefined) {
    return emptyHol;
  }            
  return currentGroupList;
}
```

Then when my `AppButton.groupCycle` is pressed, I have added `modelArr = []` to clear the array on each press, this works as intended.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about your last paragraph... what's the *database*? Is it `dataModel.calendarUserItems`? Was there a specific error message?

Comment: Hi @TrebledJ apologies, I have edited both question and answer! Hopefully this is clearer for you now! Thanks!